# Creating a url which is accessed by anonymous users

Tags: apex, visualforce, public

I need to create a URL to which an external system post some information. Basically, it is a redirect to the particular URL from the external URL and it posts some data by passing the parameters.

The URL need to be available to anonymous users without setting up a public site. Is it achievable via an external app?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.

At some point without a public site you *will have to authenticate*.

To that end, you could make an external website that would take their post and then login using an API user - but why. At that point just make a public site as there would not really be any difference.

So the question as a follow up - Why are you against a public site to achieve your goal?

Comment: This feature will be delivered to multiple orgs. So client does want to take the overhead of configuring public site in all orgs.

Comment: No matter what you do you will have to configure something somewhere for each org. It is much easier to maintain a site (for the admin) than an external site that needs to know which URL and credentials to use depending on the destination